# windows 7 boot screen logo issue

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot

I have a problem with my Lenovo b50-70, I installed Ubuntu and Windows 7 in two different disk partitions, but when I choose Windows in the grub I see that instead of windows boot logo:

[image: 1]

So, I formatted my HD and installed only Windows and the problem was solved, but I want have Linux too on my laptop, so I installed Debian in the second partition and now I see that:

[image: 2]

After that, Windows works, but I would solve that problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add clearer screenshots if possible?

Comment: I see that: http://i.imgur.com/O0nLUs5.jpg
"Starting Windows" is on the top of the screen(the logo isn't visible, is out of screen) and in the lower side I see that: http://i.imgur.com/Dt8icRG.jpg
This happen when I have dual boot Win7/Linux, if I delete Linux partition the problem doesn't exists

Comment: Try [Boot Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved in this way:
Edit /etc/default/grub (as root) and uncomment

#    GRUB_TERMINAL="console"
(remove the #)

after that, run sudo update-grub

Comment: Good job. You should add it as an answer below, which you can self-accept after 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I've solved in this way: Edit /etc/default/grub (as root) and uncomment # GRUB_TERMINAL="console" (remove the #) after that, run sudo update-grub